# What does the '*' in this code mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code:

```
$("body").on("click","*",function(){})
```

What does the '*' mean?

Comment: every element with in body this handler will trigger ...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: where did you find it? I don't think that is really required

Comment: its the brother of  * from sql  "select * from users" :)

Answer (score 2):

This means that, on UI if you will click on any `element`, this function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

On jQuery 'on' attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

On your case is the body.

The '*' is the all selector (or universal selector) and it selects all elements.

The 'on' body is executed when click on any element inside the ''

> Be careful using this selector, it's extremely slow, except when used
>   by itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
/*the above code ll only execute paragraph*/


$( "body" ).on( "click", "*", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
/*the above code ll only execute all tags...*/
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to filter descendants.

If you specify an event on an element, it can catch unhandled events triggered on it's children (eg. you put it on a DIV to catch all clicks on the anchors inside).

With the descendant filter selector, you can specify which descendants you want to listen for, eg. you can only listen for clicks on P tags, discarding (== letting it bubble up the chain) others.